# ElectronJS printToPDF - is there an option to set the page width dynamically?

Tags: electron

**How to pass page settings dynamically to the main process from renderer process in ElectronJS?**

I wanted to pass the page settings dynamically from the renderer process to the main process. Basically the printToPDF function in main process should take the pageSettings object and print accordingly. The intention is to dynamically set the page width.

The code in brief is as follows. But it doesn't work.

```
//Sending from Renderer Process
ipc.send("readyToPrint", page_settings);


//Receiving at Main Process
ipc.on("readyToPrint", (event, page_settings) => {

  const pdfPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'print.pdf');

  /* Default Settings
    var pageSettings = {
      'marginsType': 1,
      'printBackground': true, 
      'pageSize': {
        "height": 297000,
        "width": 72000
      }
    }
  */

  var pageSettings = page_settings;

  workerWindow.webContents.printToPDF(pageSettings, function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error
        fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                throw error
            }
            shell.openItem(pdfPath);
        })
  })
});
```